# Replacing variable in function definition

Tags: function-construction, replacement

I would like to have a series of functions that depend one another, indexed by a number, and that are defined via a Do loop. However, Mathematica seems unable to replace the index in the loop. My trial code:

```
Do[
  If[i == 1,
    ff[i, x_, y_] := x + y;,
    ff[i, x_, y_] := (x - y)*ff[i - 1, x, y];
    ];
  , {i, 1, 2}];
ff[2, x, y]
```

Output:
(x - y) ff[-1 + i, x, y]

Desired output is however:
(x - y)(x + y)

This thing surprises me since if I manually define

```
ff[2, x_, y_] := (x - y)*ff[1, x, y];
```

then I get the desired output. It seems that the Do loop is not replacing inside the function.

Is this normal? :-o

Answer (score 4):

In your [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) loop use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) for the RHS to be evaluated.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) to directly obtain a closed-form solution for the nth function

```
ff[n_, x_, y_] = 
 f[n] /. RSolve[{f[1] == x + y, f[n] == (x - y)*f[n - 1]}, f[n], n][[1]]

(* (x - y)^(-1 + n) (x + y) *)
```

Alternatively, using explicit recursion

```
f2[1] = x + y;
f2[n_] := f2[n] = (x - y)*f2[n - 1]
```

Generating a sequence from the recursion

```
seq = f2 /@ Range[5]

(* {x + y, (x - y) (x + y), (x - y)^2 (x + y), (x - y)^3 (x + y), 
    (x - y)^4 (x + y)} *)
```

Then using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize from the sequence, the result is identical to that provided by `RSolve`

```
FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] === ff[n, x, y]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution but I think it's too much writing for such a simple thing. 
All this is really weird in Mathematica (IMHO). In any standard programming language the set-delayed involves only the parameters of a function (the ones with underscore, here). The rest is replaced instantaneously. 
Sometimes Evaluate[..] helps, but here Evaluate[i-1] does not.

I found a simplest solution with:
Do[
  If[i == 1,
    ff[i, x_, y_] := x + y;,
    pp = i;
    ff[i, x_, y_] := (x - y)*ff[pp - 1, x, y];
    ];
  , {i, 1, 2}];
ff[2, x, y]
which I think it forces the i-replacement.

Comment: I don't understand your objection. `ff[n_, x_, y_] = 
 f[n] /. RSolve[{f[1] == x + y, f[n] == (x - y)*f[n - 1]}, f[n], n][[1]]` is shorter than your code, works for arbitrary `n`, and is more efficient. The remainder of the post was just to demonstrate an alternate approach.